# freq() renames columns during printing

Tags: r, plyr

I want to get a one-way frequency table for each column in my dataframe (a count of each unique value in each column). I am following [this tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-get-the-frequency-table-of-a-categorical-variable-as-a-data-frame-in-r/), which suggests using the count() function from the `plyr` package.

```
for (col in mtcars[c("gear","carb")]){
 freq <- count(col)
 write.table(freq, file='filename.txt')
}
```

I would expect the output to look like this:

```
  gear  freq
1 3     15
2 4     12
3 5     5
```

Instead the column name is replaced with 'x':

```
  x freq
1 3   15
2 4   12
3 5    5
```

Why is this happening, and how can I modify my for loop so that it prints the column name instead of 'x'?

(There is probably a better, vectorized way to do this other than using a for loop, but I'm new to R and can't quite figure out the syntax.)

Comment: Where is the `count` function from? Also, think about the value of `col` in the loop. Is it a vector? Is it a data.frame? Does it have names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `for` loop:

```
for (col in c("gear","carb")){
  print(plyr::count(mtcars, col))
}
```

Using `lapply()`:

```
lapply(c("gear","carb"), function(col) plyr::count(mtcars, col))
```

To be clear, `count` is not renaming anything. In your loop it receives `col` which is a vector. A vector does not have column names, and so `count` does not know what name it should use. It uses `x` as a place holder.

Answer (score 1):

This will also work (with the names of the columns of the dataset mtcar as input, with result as a list of dataframes):

```
lapply(c("gear","carb"), function(x){df <- as.data.frame(table(mtcars[x])); names(df) <- c(x, 'freq'); df})

[[1]]
  gear freq
1    3   15
2    4   12
3    5    5

[[2]]
  carb freq
1    1    7
2    2   10
3    3    3
4    4   10
5    6    1
6    8    1
```